# How to wirite a Node.js express server to receive curl POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl

My curl post message is as follow:

```
curl -X POST -H "application/json" -d '{"u_username":"a"}' http://localhost:3000/save
```

My node.js server function are as follow:

```
router.post('/save', function (req, res) {
     console.log(req.body);
});
```

what I expect console log is {u_username:a},
but I actually get { '\'{u_username:a}\'': '' }

Is anybody I tell me why?

I am a starter to learn node.js

Comment: In your -H param shouldnt it be 'Content-Type:application/json'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `-H` header should be `"Content-Type: application/json"` not just `"application/json"`.